# Is there a Solo Leonis Battle in the Second Generation

Tags: record-of-agarest-war-zero

i have my party formation rigged up so that with Alice, no enemy is unreachable, however i'm tossing up between having Leonis or Sieghert as both have similar extended ranges, the only difference between them is that Leon can boost SP to toe party while Sieg can boost AP.

at the moment i keep Leon in the party out of fear that there is a solo battle where he is the only member of the party and having not been in the party, will take forever to grind, so i am wondering if there is a Solo Battle with Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been some time since I played but no I do not believe that there are any solo fights in the second generation. Since the main focus of combat is to chain attacks with other members they tend to avoid solo fights.